# Extract values from a Java String

Tags: java, string

I have Java string('s) in the format below:

```
String s = "[
    "samsung",

    ["samsung galaxy s9 case","samsung galaxy s8 case","samsung galaxy s9 plus case","samsung galaxy s8 charger"],

    [{"nodes":[{"name":"Cell Phones & Accessories","alias":"mobile"}]},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],

    [],

    "1XQ3CN8WM8VSE"
]"
```

What's the best way to process the String so I can get these values (of 2nd item enclosed with [])

```
"samsung galaxy s9 case","samsung galaxy s8 case","samsung galaxy s9 plus case","samsung galaxy s8 charger"
```

inside a `List<String>`?

Update

The String is valid JSON and tested with the code

```
public static boolean isJSONValid(String test) {
        try {
            new JSONObject(test);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            // edited, to include @Arthur's comment
            // e.g. in case JSONArray is valid as well...
            try {
                new JSONArray(test);
            } catch (JSONException ex1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I also tried to parse it as JSON (as suggested) but I get exception provided.

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1] .

My String always starts with [..]

Comment: if its valid JSON you can use a parser like jackson or gson

Comment: Its a valid JSON and this is waht I was trying for the last few minutes. My codes doesn't work out :| . So if you can show, this will also work out. However, I believe that using the regex to process will be better idea for the example.

Comment: @Arefe Where is the code that doesn't work ?

Comment: `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);`
\n
`Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]` . My String always start with [..]

Comment: Please don't try to post code as a comment on your question.  Instead, just [edit] your question to add any additional information that is required to answer it.

Comment: *"I believe that using the regex to process will be better idea"* You believe wrong. Using regex is a terrible idea for parsing JSON.

Comment: The JSON code fails because the JSON text is a JSON *Array* (starts with `[`), not a JSON *Object* (starts with `{`). Use `new JSONArray(test)` instead. Please learn JSON if you're going to work with it. See http://json.org/

Comment: @Andreas yes, this helps to solve and way better than the regex. It took only 3 LOC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That format is not a valid json that´s why you are getting that error, one simple way to get the String you want is using an split method and then storage it in the your prefer collections.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String s = "[samsung,[\"samsung galaxy s9 case\",\"samsung galaxy s8 case\",\"samsung galaxy s9 plus case\",\"samsung galaxy s8 charger\"],[{\"nodes\":[{\"name\":\"Cell Phones & Accessories\",\"alias\":\"mobile\"}]},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],[],\"1XQ3CN8WM8VSE\"]";

    String[] splitedFullString = s.split(",\\[");
    String sequence = splitedFullString[1];
    sequence = sequence.replaceAll("]", "");
    sequence = sequence.replaceAll("\"", "");
    String[] splitSequence = sequence.split(",");

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
    for(String item : splitSequence){
        list.add(item);
    }
    for(String item : list){
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I write the code with the help of the answer of Andreas,

```
    JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(s);

    String str = obj.get(1).toString();
    String[] arr = str.substring(1, str.length()-1).split(",");
```

This works fine now. Thank you.